# Understanding gaussian in linear regression

Tags: probability, geometry, statistics, bayesian, linear-regression

I am looking at a figure that shows how the prior/posterior distribution vary in linear regression [image]

I don't quite understand why the Gaussians become tilted and smaller when the lines tend to fit the point.

Could someone explain this behavior? I'd like to understand the intuition behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for simple Bayesian linear regression, we assume that the true model is $w_0 + w_1 x$, where $w_0$ and $w_1$ are the true parameter values and for which we would like to find out. This means that our parameter space is $\mathbb{R}^2$, and our parameter vector is $w = (w_0, w_1)$. So, every point in the first plot corresponds to a particular straight line (every $(w_0, w_1)$ coordinate gives me a new line $w_0 + w_1 x$).

In the Bayesian approach, we place a prior distribution on the parameter space, which means we put a probability distribution on the space of parameters $\mathbb{R}^2$. In this case, we don't really know where the parameters are, so we just put a mean zero Gaussian with large variance.

If we sample a few times from this Gaussian, we'll get a bunch of coordinates, and each coordinate gives a bunch of lines, we can plot these lines in the top right plot. See how these lines are all over the place, this is because we haven't seen any data and the prior just spreads the probability over the unit square.

Next, we observe a data point. We started off with our prior belief, but now can move on to incorporating the data into our understanding of the problem. This is called computing the posterior distribution. The posterior distribution will be a more concentrated distribution that uses the data to refine our estimate of where the true parameters $(w_0, w_1)$ actually are. So we get a tighter gaussian. Now, if we sample from this distribution a bunch of times, we get a bunch of lines again, which are starting to look a bit more concentrated.

Now, we start the whole process again, but we use the old posterior as our new prior. We see some more data, compute the new posterior and so on. As we see more data, our belief on where the true parameter values are becomes better and better, and the possible models (straight lines) that we think are probable become more and more concentrated.

That is the intuition, for the mathematical detail of computing posteriors refer to the text you're reading :)

Comment: thanks! Just wondering, what does it mean in words when I draw a vertical line passing through $w_0$  that intersects with the gaussian? I don't quite understand the significance of the red/yellow/green regions

Comment: @nz_21 there is no vertical line passing through w0, this is just the contours of the gaussian, green regions are areas with lower density. The true parameter value is indicated with a + in those images. If the answer is helpful to you, you can upvote/accept it

Comment: just to clarify, if the prior is spherical, does this mean that the assumption is that the gaussian has a mean zero and large variance? (sorry if it's obvious, I'm very new to this)

Comment: @nz_21 no, the mean is the point at the centre of the circle, so (0,0) in the first plot, the fact that it is spherical tells us that we are assigning equal probability in each direction. When the Gaussian becomes more elliptical, it is assigning no probability to some directions and more to others - in other words our beliefs are a bit more refined. See here for a better understanding of multivariate gaussians https://maitra.public.iastate.edu/stat501/lectures/MultivariateNormalDistribution-I.pdf

Comment: thanks, you've been quite helpful!